# Presenting a scrollable user control within a view

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I have a WPF view that encompass a user control as part of it. After wrapping the user control with a ScrollViewer control I'm not able to scroll through the control. The vertical scroll bar shows but is not enabled.

```
----------------------
| Main View          |
|                    |
|  ----------------  |
|  | User Control |  |
L____________________|
   |______________|
```

This is how my view is layed out, and there is a `<ScrollViewer>` around the User Control but for some reason it's not scrollable.

Any help you can shed on this issue would be helpful.

Thanks.

Edit: adding sample source code:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="22" />
        <RowDefinition Height="48" />
        <RowDefinition Height="94" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="90" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="6" Margin="35,25,0,0" Width="1824" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <local:Control DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}" Margin="40,0,0,0"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Edit 2: 
The User control is made with a Canvas, thus this complicates things. So if anyone has a workaround for it that would be helpful.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: try to remove `Width="1824" ` from `ScrollViewer` and change `Grid.Row` to `Grid.Row="5"`

Comment: Removing the width doesn't change anything. Changing the grid row also didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You used Grid.Row="6" where you only have 6 rows.

Rows start with index 0 so Grid.Row="5" would be the last row.